# MySQL select max count of a column value

Tags: mysql, sql

I have table called Euro_Cup.

[enter image description here][1]

```
Group   Country Rank    Jersey  Position    Age Selections  Club    Player
A   Brazil  3   18  Midfielder  29  24  Internazionale      Hernanes
A   Cameroon    56  18  Midfielder  28  38  Antalyaspor     Eyong Enoh
A   Croatia 18  18  Forward 34  92  VfL Wolfsburg   Ivica Olic
A   Mexico  20  18  Defender    27  104 Bayer Leverkusen    Andres Guardado
B   Australia   62  18  Goalie  32  8   Adelaide United     Eugene Galekovic
B   Chile   14  18  Defender    28  65  Nottingham Forest   Gonzalo Jara
B   Spain   1   18  Defender    25  26  Barcelona       Jordi Alba
B   Netherlands 15  18  Midfielder  24  6   Norwich City    Leroy Fer
```

I have to write a SQL query to group the player by their jersey number and then, for each jersey number group, return the most common position for that jersey number.

E.g Jersey number 18 has 3 Midfilders, 8 defender and 2 Goalie then result should jersey number 18 , defender (bcos max player with jersey number number 18)

I have tried

```
 select jersey,position,count(position) as cnt 
 from euro_cup2
 group by jersey,position 
 having count(position) in 
                       (select max(cnt) from   (select jersey,position,count(position) as cnt 
                      from euro_cup2
                       group by jersey,position)a)
```

But it does not work. Any help would be highly appreciated

Comment: Your example data has **3 defender** not **8 defender**. and there is *tie* between **3 Midfilders** and **3 defender** in this case what should happen

Comment: I have pasted only sample data. But a tie is possible.

Comment: So all the other columns are irrelevant?

Comment: And in the event of a tie at the top you'd want to show all tied positions?

Comment: Fix your query as for my answer, then we can see if that is what you want. There is an SQL issue. Regards

Comment: Incidentally, with the exception of numbers 1,7,& 10, extracting any kind of meaningful information from such a query must be futile.

Comment: Do you have any feedback?

Answer (score 0):

I reviewed all your comments, this will give you what you search:

```
SELECT
euro_cup2.jersey,
a.position,
MAX(cnt) as count
FROM euro_cup2
LEFT JOIN
(SELECT
   jersey,
   position,
   (COUNT(position)) AS cnt 
   FROM euro_cup2
   GROUP BY jersey,position) AS a ON euro_cup2.jersey=a.jersey
GROUP BY jersey;
```

Here the result:

[image: Here the result]

Regards

Comment: I got your point - Subquery is results in 1 number and not a set. But

Comment: But the sub-query SELECT
    MAX(cnt)
    FROM (SELECT 
            jersey,
            position,
            COUNT(position) AS cnt 
            FROM euro_cup2
            GROUP BY jersey,position) AS a

Comment: Still result in one record only and that record the max number of position from the whole data set (32) and not max number of position of each jersey

Comment: jersey position cnt
1 Goalie 32

Comment: Are you sure? I simulated more jersey and I got the max for each, 2 lines per jersey as I put two players at 3.

Comment: yes. i tried your query pasted below in SQL workbench against MySQL data in which i have loaded by data file (CSV). It returns only 1 row.  SELECT
 jersey,
 position,
 COUNT(position) AS cnt 
 FROM euro_cup2
 GROUP BY jersey,position 
 HAVING COUNT(position) = 
 ((SELECT
    MAX(cnt)
    FROM (SELECT 
            jersey,
            position,
            COUNT(position) AS cnt 
            FROM euro_cup2
            GROUP BY jersey,position) AS a)

Comment: 3 1073 20:40:46 SELECT
  jersey,
  position,
  COUNT(position) AS cnt 
  FROM euro_cup2
  GROUP BY jersey,position 
  HAVING COUNT(position) = 
  ((SELECT
     MAX(cnt)
     FROM (SELECT 
             jersey,
             position,
             COUNT(position) AS cnt 
             FROM euro_cup2
             GROUP BY jersey,position) AS a))
 LIMIT 0, 70000 1 row(s) returned 0.016 sec / 0.000 sec

Comment: The sub-query returns multiple records for each jersey but as soon as I put SELECT MAX(cnt) on top of that - it returns only 1 row with 32 (which is maximum count.

Comment: Could you send your data set and tell me what are the incorrect results? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try this one, should work

```
   SELECT Jersey,
   Group_concat(Position separator ','),
   Group_concat(CountOfPosition separator ',')
   FROM   (SELECT euro_cup.Jersey,
           euro_cup.Position,
           Count(euro_cup.Position) AS CountOfPosition
    FROM   euro_cup
    GROUP  BY euro_cup.jersey,
              euro_cup.Position) a
   WHERE  CountOfPosition = (SELECT Max(CountOfPosition)
                     FROM   (SELECT euro_cup.jersey,
                                    euro_cup.Position,
                                    Count(euro_cup.Position) AS      CountOfPosition
                             FROM   euro_cup
                             GROUP  BY euro_cup.jersey,
                                       euro_cup.Position) b
                     WHERE  a.jersey = b.jersey)
     GROUP  BY Jersey
```